# Initialising integer array as member

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I want to initialise my a variable with  queue type. But im running into a bit of trouble. The warning says incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to int. What does this mean?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 4

struct queue
{
    int array[MAX];
    int front;
    int back;
};
typedef struct queue Queue;

Queue qInit(Queue table[], int front, int back);

int main(void)
{

    Queue table[MAX];
    int front, back;

    qInit(table, front, back);

    return 0;
}

Queue qInit(Queue table[], int front, int back)
{
    Queue c;

    c.array[MAX]=table;  // <---- getting warning right here.
    c.front=front;
    c.back=back;

    return c;
}
```

Comment: if array is in size MAX, there is no element in the index of MAX, it's only ranging from 0 to MAX-1. Aside of that, as table is an array of integers, you can't implicitly assign a pointer (table is an array, therefore a pointer) to an integer spot

Comment: @ZachP not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: Alex it is not clear what you are trying to do. The line with the warning is because array is for integers, but you are trying to put a Queue in to it. c.array[X] can only be given an integer, and X would have to be from 0 to MAX-1, because MAX is 4, the valid index to the array are 0,1,2 and 3, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is (what @Zach P is also trying to explain) array[MAX] contains MAX number of values with index 0 to MAX-1 and there is no position MAX so last index is array[MAX-1].

and secondly table is a pointer to an array so you cant assign a pointer to a int variable (array[MAX-1] is of type int)